# How to cancel a particular job in a queue?

Tags: node.js, redis, rabbitmq

I am using RabbitMQ to build a job queue.

Let's say there is a job called `DO_SOMETHING` that acts on `{ item: 'A'}` scheduled in the near future.

My queue would have jobs like:

```
[DO_SOMETHING { item: 'B' }, DO_SOMETHING { item: 'A' }, DO_SOMETHING { item: 'C' }]
```

Let's say something happens so that `DO_SOMETHING { item: 'A' }` is no longer needed.

Is there a way to selectively cancel/remove it from the queued jobs, or should I just use something like Redis?

Answer (score 0):

Cannot say that "there is no such tool", because I could be mistaken, but RabbitMQ queues are FIFO, so you always consume from the beginning - in the order jobs were produced.

Simplest solution is to check if given job has been cancelled after consuming the job and ACK to Rabbit that this job has been processed.

You could play with external mechanism, that filters deleted jobs, but that would probably require some synchronisation and other things to worry about.